# Setting title when requesting permissions?

Tags: ios, user-permissions, mpmedialibrary

I am requesting permissions for the Music Library but this question is equally appropriate for any permissions that can be requested.

I have set the key and value in the project plist:

```
Privacy - Media Library Usage Description: Access to Media Library may be required to integrate music. This can be configured in Settings.
```

I have then added the code to display the native alert:

```
MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
}
```

This is all working as expected.

The issue is that I want to set the title of the permissions alert to a custom title.

[image]

I would like a custom title instead of:

> AppName would like to access Apple Music, your music and video activity, and your media library

I can see many reasons why this wouldn't be configurable, Apple not wanting people lying, or being able to lie, about the permissions being requested being the main one.

It would be great to know whether this is possible and then any indication of how to do it if so. Otherwise the knowledge that it isn't possible is equally as valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the fixed title of the message. Your own message is shown below the bold title.

Your specific privacy message should explain to the user *why* your app needs access. That's the best you can do.

Comment: This is perfect - not knowing if something is possible is more infuriating than knowing it is possible and not being able to implement it.